# Proper VSS.register() return syntax

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-rest-api

I am fairly new to VSTS and developing custom widgets. I followed the sample tutorial: [Add a dashboard widget](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-dashboard-widget?view=vsts)

Here is the following JS code for the index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    VSS.init({                        
        explicitNotifyLoaded: true,
        usePlatformStyles: true
    });

    VSS.require("TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", function (WidgetHelpers) {
        WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
        VSS.register("HelloWorldWidget", function () {                
            return {
                load: function (widgetSettings) {
                    var $title = $('h2.title');
                    $title.text('Hello World');

                    return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
                }
            }
        });
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    });
</script>
```

**Notice**: This is a very simple example as there are **NO** VSS API calls or ajax requests.

> What does `return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();` accomplish? I also don't understand what `VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();` does. If  I wanted to make API calls via ajax (asynchronous requests), then where in my code would I place these statements?

Take a look at the following lines of code that *seems* to work... I am unsure if this is the proper way to use these VSS statements:

```
VSS.require(["TFS/Dashboards/WidgetHelpers", "VSS/Authentication/Services"], function (WidgetHelpers, VSS_Auth_Service) {
        WidgetHelpers.IncludeWidgetStyles();
        VSS.register("ajaxrequesttest", function () {
            var makeRequest = function (widgetSettings) {
                VSS.getAccessToken().then(function (token) {
                    // Format the auth header
                    var authHeader = VSS_Auth_Service.authTokenManager.getAuthorizationHeader(token);
                    var epicId = '#####';
                    var epicUrl = `https://myurl/${epicId}`;
                    //Make Ajax Request
                    $.ajax(epicUrl, {
                        headers: {
                            "Authorization": authHeader
                        },
                        timeout: 10000,
                        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                            $('#myText').text("Success!");
                            var $list = $('<ul>');
                            $list.append($('<li>').text("Response: " + JSON.stringify(data)));
                            $('#myText').append($list);
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            $('#myText').text("Error!");
                            return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Failure(error.message);
                        }
                    });
                });
                return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success();
            }
            return {
                load: function (widgetSettings) {
                    var $title = $('h2.title');
                    $title.text('Ajax Request Test');

                    return makeRequest(widgetSettings);
                }
            }
        });
        VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded();
    });
```

If someone can answer the following bullets that would be great:

- What does WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success() do?
- What does VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded() do?
- When and where should I use them?
- Is there any documentation on the functions provided by VSS.Services? For example when I require 'VSS/Authentication/Services' how am I supposed to know how to use VSS_Auth_Service without looking at that one tutorial for it? Is there an API reference doc somewhere for all the clients?

**Note**: The following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=vsts) is not helpful because it is missing specific function calls for specific services in the require for example...

Answer (score 2):

For your questions:

> What does WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success() do?

`WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success()` is use for telling things in `function (widgetSettings)` have been execute successfully. And you can also refer the blog [Creating a VSTS dashboard widget](https://blogs.infosupport.com/creating-a-vsts-dashboard-widget/).

```
What does VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded() do?
```

`VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded()` is use for showing the required libraries are loaded successfully. As [the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/reference/client/core-sdk?view=vsts#notifyloadsucceeded()) describes:

*Notifies the host that the extension successfully loaded (stop showing the loading indicator)*

> When and where should I use them?

`WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success()` is needed at the end ofthe load or reload something. And `VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded()` is needed at the end of the callback to indicate the extension successfully loaded.

> Is there any documentation on the functions provided by VSS.Services?
>   For example when I require 'VSS/Authentication/Services' how am I
>   supposed to know how to use VSS_Auth_Service without looking at that
>   one tutorial for it? Is there an API reference doc somewhere for all
>   the clients?

Unfortunately, there is no such documents excepte the [Visual Studio Services Web Extension SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vss-web-extension-sdk#visual-studio-services-web-extension-sdk) and [some example extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples).

Comment: The problem is that the extension can be loaded properly but in the middle of an asynchronous request. For example, in the load function I call a function that fires some ajax requests. By the time the requests come back the function would have returned already and therefore I am confused when to return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success(), and when to execute the VSS.notifyLoadSucceeded() statement. In the VSTS example they wrote a function to return WidgetHelpers.WidgetStatusHelper.Success() in a .then() block, not pure AJAX. Do I return in the success block of the AJAX request?

Comment: Can you share the whole extension you attempted?